# Solution deployment stuck on deploying SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, solution-package

Those are the properties of my wsp :

[image]

I use SPSD to deploy my solution, there is no error on SPSD log and SP log .

I Restarted the SharePoint Timer service and the administration services on all my front-end server. The issue is the status of solution deployment stuck on deploying. I check: the features are created on my all front-end server, the bin is on the virtual directory folder. I even restart all the server ? but the issue still the same.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you go to Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Farm Solutions and check on the status there? I would try canceling the deployment from there and see if you can retry.

Comment: when i cancel the  deployment teh status change to deployed , but it's not the right way , is that ?

Comment: No, but canceling the deployment should let you try to deploy it again. Managing the solution through Central Admin is sort of a last-ditch fix... Does the solution hang every time you deploy or is this just a fluke?

Comment: yes the solution hang every time I deploy, i even restart the timer jobs on all server.I wish i could know what it try to to do ?

Comment: what method you are using the to deploy the solution? i am sorry but i dont know what is SPSD?

Comment: I use https://spsd.codeplex.com/ solution deployer

Comment: SO it finally works , it's a SP probleme , what i did is:1- i restart all my timer job with PShell 2-restart all my front-end server 3- readjust my timer out . and i deply the wsp . and if the first time did not work just try to redeply for the second time and it pass normally !!

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have followed below steps to deploy the solution:

1. I have cancel my solution deployment from central admin.
2. I have restarted **SharePoint Timer Service** in all my SP instance.
3. I stopped **SharePoint Administration service** in all SP instances.
4. I have deployed my solution from central admin. (keep continue even if it gave an error)
5. I have executed below command in all SP instance in Command Prompt (administrative)
   stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs
6. Refresh deployment page. It shows deployment success message

Answer (score 2):

So it finally works , it's a SP problem , what I did is:

1. I restart all my timer job with PShell

stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs

or

```
[array]$servers= Get-SPServer | ? {$_.Role -eq "Application"}            
$farm = Get-SPFarm            
foreach ($server in $servers)            
{            
    Write-Host "Restarting Timer Job on $server"                                      
    $Service = Get-WmiObject -Computer $server.name Win32_Service -Filter "Name='SPTimerV4'"                        
    if ($Service -ne $null)                         
    {                             
        $Service.InvokeMethod('StopService',$null)            
        Start-Sleep -s 7            
        $service.InvokeMethod('StartService',$null)                             
        Start-Sleep -s 7            
        Write-Host "Timer Job successfully restarted on $server"                        
    }             
    else            
    {            
        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow "Could not find SharePoint 2010 Timer Service on $server"            
    }            
}
```

2. Restart all my front-end server
3. Readjust my timer out. and I deploy the wsp .

And if the first time did not work just try to redeploy for the second time and it pass normally !!

Comment: still same issue. Any other way?